# Django+React: Uploading images to Django media inserted in a Rich Text editor via React

Tags: django, reactjs

I have a project that ***solely*** utilizes **Django** as **web API server** and **React** as its **frontend**. And I am using **Django Rest Framework** (DRF) for `RESTful API` implementation.

In this project, I am working on an `article module` where an author can insert `one or more images` in between text contents in a `rich text editor`. Do you have any idea as to the process of communicating React with Django in order to upload those inserted images to my `media` folder?

For sure, the entire article content will be saved as a `code snippet` *(as generated by the `rich text editor`)* that will contain `img` tags of the inserted images. This `code snippet` will be saved in my model's `content` field (`TextField`).

**Here is my `Article` model's struct:**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="", unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleCategory, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="article_category")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="article_author")
    content = models.TextField()
    feature_image = models.FileField(
        upload_to='article_images/'+str(current_date.year) + "/" + current_date.strftime('%B'))
    feature_image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField()
    unpublish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    preapproved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    preapproved_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="article_preapproved_by", blank=True, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="article_approved_by", blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="article_updated_by", blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```